# Standard Visitor Visa refusal grounds V 4.2 (e) (opacity)

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for UK visa 3 weeks back and today I collected my documents. My application has been refused with following reason:

> - You state that the cost to you personally is 500 (GBP)  and that you are employed as xxx and receive a monthly income of yyyy. As
>     evidence of your funds you have submitted a photocopy of your bank
>     statement however, I am unable to see a salary being deposited to the
>     amount stated in your application for and therefore I am not satisfied
>     that your income or employment is as stated.
>
> In light of the above, I am not satisfied that you have sufficient
>   funds to cover your costs whilst in the UK without working or
>   accessing public fund. You application has therefore been refused
>   under paragraph V4.2 (e).

I didn't attach any playslip or any proof of employment. I had just attached NOC from employer, bank statements and tax returns as part of financial.

I have been working in a startup for last 10 months and it doesn't pay me regularly. Although over a period of 8-9 months, total amount deposited by company is same as the amount stated in my application. Generally employer transfers 2-3 times of my stated salary once and for next 2-3 months there are no deposits.

Should I apply again with more documents, such as letter of employment from company, salary slip and proof of income?

I have flight tickets booked for Saturday (3rd June). Will going for priority visa help my case. Although there is a visa application center in my city, all applications are sent to different city for processing. I am planning to book an appointment for Monday and travel to that city to get it done.

Questions:

1. How to document the case of irregular payments?
2. What type of documents should I get from the company?
3. What do I need to ensure in the application considering refusal?
4. What is the general timeline for priority visa? I know official site says 5 days, but I guess it decided earlier
5. Is it worth trying again considering travel date is hardly a week away?

Answer (score 11):

You were refused a Standard Visitor Visa on grounds V 4.2 (e). It means you showed insufficient funds. Let's have a look at some of the issues...

They wrote...

> As evidence of your funds you have submitted a photocopy of your bank
>   statement

The guidance calls for originals in English; translations must be independently verified.

The ECO wrote "a photocopy", meaning that you submitted a single statement. We point out [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) that this is an opaque strategy. Its profile looks like this...[image]

With a single statement, the ECO cannot get a broader view of your lifestyle and stability.  Although you may not be hiding something, an opaque banking history makes the ECO suspicious.

You wrote...

> I didn't attach any playslip or any proof of employment.

Why not? The application calls for evidence of employment (or a viable substitute) and again your opacity created suspicion.

> I had just attached NOC from employer, bank statements and tax returns
>   as part of financial.

The ECO said you provided a single statement, you are using the plural. Tax returns are good, but the NOC doesn't count for much without your employment contract as backing evidence.

You wrote...

> I have been working in a startup for last 10 months and it doesn't pay
>   me regularly. Although over a period of 8-9 months, total amount
>   deposited by company is same as the amount stated in my application.
>   Generally employer transfers 2-3 times of my stated salary once and
>   for next 2-3 months there are no deposits.

This condition would be spelled out in your employment contract and your bank statements should cover your entire period of employment so that the information you gave in your application ties out to the evidence.

When a person is paid at irregular intervals, they should include pay slips and bank statements for the history of their employment (up to several years if warranted). This would provide the transparency that the ECO needs to see.  If you are unable (or unwilling) to provide that evidence, it may be better to put off your application indefinitely (or until your evidence improves).

> I have flight tickets booked for Saturday (3rd June). Will going for
>   priority visa help my case.

You purchased flight tickets in advance of a visa decision. This is a dangerous strategy because you may have to abandon them (or refund them, or sell them, etc).  Unlike other regimes, the UK is very clear that flight tickets should not be purchased until after a decision has been made.

Your questions are...

> How to document the case of irregular payments?

Include your employment contract and **original** bank statements and pay slips (translated if they are not in English). They have no problem with irregular payments, but they have a *big* problem with opacity.

> What type of documents should I get from the company?

Your employment contract and pay slips, and once you have those, an NOC can be helpful (but not very much).

> What do I need to ensure in the application considering refusal?

You can instruct a member of the [UK Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) to manage your application. The membership organisation for those with a practice area in immigration is [ILPA](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/pages/about-us.html).  Most people do not use a solicitor, but it is the only way to absolutely guarantee success (or they will refuse the case) and that's the way your question is framed.

> What is the general timeline for priority visa? I know official site
>   says 5 days, but I guess it decided earlier

If you have a refusal in your history (which you do), you will not qualify for priority service (it's somewhere in the small print). If you purchase the priority service, they will collect your money and put your application in the 'complex' queue.

> Is it worth trying again considering travel date is hardly a week
>   away?

This is soliciting an opinion. My opinion is that 'complex' cases are processed much slower because they need to go to the second and third levels of enquiry. I don't think a week is realistic, but your mileage may vary and some may think a week is sufficient.

---

At a minimum you should give a close read of the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents).

The visitor rules are in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

---

.

Comment: 1. I had attached bank statements for last 6 months.

2. Bank provides only copy of bank statements stamped and signed by authorised person. I had attached those copies only.

Comment: I have to travel to UK to attend a cricket match  of ICC champions trophy as the representative of a company who are official sponsors of the team in the tournament. I don't work for that company and they are  sponsoring some fans for 2 matches. 

They had contracted travel and visa arrangements to 2 companies and they booked my appointment. 

I got all the information a day before appointment only and I attached all the documents which they had asked me for. 

Tickets were booked by them only.

Comment: I believe I could have handled it better if I was doing everything on my own and this time I want to apply on priority basis as all arrangements are already done and in case it is processed before travel date, I would great, otherwise in case of late approval, I would lose the visa fees.

Comment: So I applied again on priority basis and got the visa in 2 days.